# Is there any historical evidence of this quote E.T. Bell attributed to C.G.J. Jacobi?

Tags: mathematicians, reference-request

I read *Men of Mathematics* by E.T. Bell long ago, and this quote he attributed to Jacobi stuck with me:

> Certainly I have sometimes endangered my health from overwork, but what of it? Only cabbages have no nerves, no worries. And what do they get out of their perfect wellbeing?

I'm aware that the book is not to be taken as a work of historical scholarship, so I was looking for some other reference.  I googled “Jacobi cabbage” and didn't find anything but a Google Books hit back to *Men of Mathematics*, and many recipes.  So is this story totally aprocryphal?

Comment: If E.T. Bell gives you a neat quip or story you can bet that he just made it up. "Apocryphal" makes it sound almost respectable. That all mentions trace back to Men of Mathematics, which, of course, gives no reference, is a telltale sign.

Comment: If Jacobi did say it, he wouldn't have said it in English.